# python extracting zip files with wordlist not working and just keeps looping lines

Tags: python, passwords

here the code:

```
import os
import rarfile
import zipfile
import threading


while True:
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\omri\\Desktop\\"):
        for zip_rar_filename in files:
            if zip_rar_filename.endswith(".zip"):
                print(f'{zip_rar_filename} found')
                try:
                    with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(path, zip_rar_filename)) as zipper:
                        zipper.extractall()
                except PermissionError and RuntimeError:
                        print("files protected with password!")
                        x = input("would you like to try and crack them? \nyes/no\n>> ")
                        if x == "yes".lower():
                                with open("C:\\Users\\omri\\Desktop\\rockyou.txt","r", encoding="utf-8") as passcracking:
                                    id = 0
                                    for lines in passcracking.readlines():
                                        for line in lines:
                                            pwd = lines.strip()
                                            with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(path, zip_rar_filename)) as zipper:
                                                try:
                                                    id += 1
                                                    print(f"trying pass {lines}")
                                                    zipper.extractall(zip_rar_filename, "C:\\temp\\",pwd=pwd.encode())
                                                except:
                                                    continue
                                                else:
                                                    print(f"pass {pwd.decode()} found")
                                                    exit(0)
```

i was excepting the code to eventually stop at the "else" statement and print the password that the program catched

Comment: ahh, I see 13 level deep indentation. Try looking at python functions to simplify the code, and increase the code readability.

Comment: `if x == "yes".lower():` - "yes" is already lower. You probably want `if x.lower() == "yes":` `pwd = lines.strip()` perhaps you mean `pwd = line.strip()`? `print(f"trying pass {lines}")` same here - plural vs. singular. `except PermissionError and RuntimeError:` I'm not sure what python does with this, usually a tuple is used.